# mixed extended ascii and normal string while scraping html

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm learning the document of scrapy(https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/intro/tutorial.html), but there is a paragraph of code, my computer generate different results.

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }
```

The right output should be:

{"text": ""The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking."", "author": "Albert Einstein", "tags": ["change", "deep-thoughts", "thinking", "world"]}

But my output(in json) is:

{"text": "\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d", "author": "Albert Einstein", "tags": ["change", "deep-thoughts", "thinking", "world"]}

It happens when I use scrapy shell or try to output a json file. But if I choose to output into csv, it works normally. Any one have the solution?

Env: Ubuntu, python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's ok that it is encoded like that, most programs that will load it, will decode it as necessary.

If you insist of encoding the JSON output in another way you can use Scrapy's `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` settings [as stated here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING).

What I guess you are looking for is `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` (in your settings.py file)

Comment: Many thanks! It bothered me for a while! You suggestion works perfectly! :)